# core data model mapping of attribute based on attribute of other entity

Tags: iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

i have a data model with two entities with a one-to-many relationship

```
Person {
    name:string, 
    type:number, 
    files<-->>File
}

File {
    reference:string, 
    person<<-->Person
}
```

i have updated the data model, removed the type attribute from Person, but the reference attribute of the File is dependent on the type of the Person : if type is 0, then reference must be "A", if type is 1, then the reference must be "B".

I cannot find a solution that can perform this mapping. Any idea's ?

EDIT :

I found a solution by creating two entity mappings, using the filter predicates to distinguish between type 0 and 1. For entity mapping with Person.type == 0, i set a hard coded attribute mapping of "A", and similar for type == 1>

Answer (score 0):

If you have two kinds of relationships to files and no type attribute to keep track of it, you should perhaps consider simply having two relationships.

```
Person {
   name
   filesA <--->> File
   filesB <--->> File
}

File {
   reference
   personsTypeA <<---> Person
   personsTypeB <<---> Person
}
```

Frankly, I think the design with the type attribute seemed far more elegant. It is flexible and allows for easy expansions of the model in the future.